# GitPython not showing latest commit

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm working on a documentation automation system. Part of that requires me to check a repo's last two commits and check the diffs and then that will trigger several events based on the results. I'm on a Mac, Catalina, with Python 3.7.7.

I have a test repo up on BitBucket. I just made some changes to the readme file, editing and committing it directly in BitBucket. I can see the change in BitBucket:

[BitBucket Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoFvT.png)

If I hop on Terminal, cd to the repo and check status I get the expected results:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

My Python script however keeps returning the previous commit. (Should note I have been programming for a bit but am new to Python)

Here's the relevant code:

```
import os, sys, git, time
from pathlib import Path

...

#get the repo
from git import Repo
thisRepo = Repo(thisRepoPath)

#fetch the repo first to make sure we capture any changes
for remote in thisRepo.remotes:
    remote.fetch()

#check the diffs
getGitDiff(thisRepo, thisRepoPath)
```

#### getGitDiff

```
def getGitDiff(thisRepo, thisRepoPath):
    printInCyan("Checking:\n" + thisRepoPath)

    #give us read only access to the repo
    thisRepo.config_reader()

    #check to see if files have been changed in the repo and that change was a modification
    print(getStatus(thisRepo, thisRepoPath))
```

#### getStatus

```
def getStatus(thisRepo, path):

    printInRed(thisRepo.head.commit.message)
    printInYellow(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M", time.gmtime(thisRepo.head.commit.committed_date)))

    changed = [ item.a_path for item in thisRepo.index.diff(None) ]
    result = {}
    if path in changed:
         result['status'] = 'modified'
         result['hasChange'] = True
         result['item'] = changed
    else:
        result['status'] = 'up-to-date'
        result['hasChange'] = False
        result['item'] = changed

    return result
```

Printing out the commit message and commit date verifies it is reading the wrong commit. I have already built something similar as a Mac desktop app and I had run into a similar issue and resolved it by calling git fetch. I'm assuming (hopefully correctly) that this is a similar problem and I am just not making the correct call or making the correct call incorrectly. : )

Any help would be appreciated. (I'm running the script in Terminal).